# How do I properly wash bugs out of green onion?

Tags: vegetables

How do I remove bugs from the inside and outside of green onions? I don't want to split open the green onion just to remove them, and washing them thoroughly in cold water seems to get the onions soggy.

Answer (score 2):

I'd cut the root off (so you have a green onion 'straw') and run water through that. This would leave the onion soggy. At this point I would lay out some paper towels at the bottom of a vase and leave the green onions upright for about an hour - switching the paper towels every 20 minutes if they get too damp. After said hour, store in a cool place.

Do note that by cutting the roots of the green onion you considerably shorten their lifespan in storage. However, you can then take the roots and plant them (after soaking the roots in 1/4 water-to-root-height ratio) to get more green onions :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you mean creepy crawlies or bacteria. If the former and its a real problem, you have to wash thoroughly or just ditch them. If bacterial, I've never heard of this as a real problem.  Prep advice taken from the UK Good Food Guide is 'Wash, then trim off the root as well as any ragged ends at the top. Slice the bulb into rounds. Cut the green tops across (kitchen scissors are good for this) or lengthways with a knife, then lengthways again, according to what shape you'd like'. I would also strip off any hard papery outside layers.